# What is the state of SWT to WPF port?

Tags: wpf, eclipse, swt

A while ago I read about a WPF port of Eclipse and SWT. I can't find any recent information about it.

What is the current status of the WPF port? Will it be available before E4?

Any other details about the implementation also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eclipse project has a Windows/WPF implementation of SWT since its 3.3 version. This doesn't mean something like XAML-Support or such things. It simply provides a way to render SWT widgets with WPF instead of the Win32 API.

If you're looking for something like XAML there is a project from a company called Soyatec (eFace) which provides a XAML-Implementation atop of SWT.

For the e4 1.0 Release there will also be a new technology called XWT which provides a small XML-Layer atop of SWT to allow declarative declaration of UIs. It has support for Databinding, Triggers, etc. For further information see http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT.